# is there anyway to know which values of a set of option for an WHERE IN clause were the ones that matched?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out if this is possible (I think its not).

I have a query

```
Select ID from table, where table.someCode IN (code1,code2,code3...)
```

As result of this query, I will get all the rows that matches this paramenter.

My question basically is, there is a way to return which was the code that matched, or codes that matched? like : `code1,code3` matched?

Thanks

EDIT ----------------------------

For example, I have rows like this

```
ID 1
name somename
somecode abc


ID 2
name someothername
somecode def


ID 3
name someotherothername
somecode qwer
```

So, I want to make a `select ID from table, where somecode IN (abc,asdf,wefwerw,qwer, etc...)`

But I want also to know (without using a loop in programming to go to each result and collect all the codes), which codes from the list of IN matched, in my example, `abc,qwer`

Any idea?

Comment: Wouldn't your result set only contain the ids that matched?

Comment: Hi, Ive updated my question, the where clause doesnt apply over the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the select * then you'll have to either have your invoking code figure it out while parsing/looping through results or you'll need another query (eg SELECT distinct(id) FROM table where table.id IN (...), -or- SELECT id, count(*) from table where table.id IN (...) group by id;)

--- EDITED ANSWER:

nah you cant do that. sorry man.

here's examples of some mysql-only things you can do:
(i'll fill this in in a few minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You could select the unique identifier that identifies each of them. Each of them must have a primary key. Your select by printing `ID` for each of them will print the ones that matched, `code1` is printed iff `code1 = ID`, `code2` is printed iff `code2 = ID` and so on.

UPDATE: Just change to `SELECT ID, code`.